# Fade toggle jquery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to use animation using jquery to toggle between fade in and fade out class called hidden.

My jquery looks like this:

```
function slide() {
    $('.additional-perspectives medium-picture shadow last').slideToggle("fast");
    ($("#perNum").text() === "+2") ? 
        $("#perNum").text("Changed") + $(".picture-hidd").removeClass('hidden') :
        $("#perNum").text("+2") + $(".picture-hidd").addClass('hidden');
}
```

when class hidden removed elements will fade in 0.5 second, when class hidden added elements fade out 0.5 second.

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 function slide() {
    $('.additional-perspectives medium-picture shadow last').slideToggle("fast");
    if($("#perNum").text() === "+2") 
    {
       $("#perNum").text("Changed");
       $(".picture-hidd").fadeIn(1000, function() { 
            $(".picture-hidd").removeClass('hidden');
       });

    }
    else
    {
       $("#perNum").text("+2");          
       $(".picture-hidd").fadeOut(1000, function() { 
               $(".picture-hidd").addClass('hidden');
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function slide() {
    $('.additional-perspectives medium-picture shadow last').slideToggle("fast");
    if($("#perNum").text() === "+2") 
    {
       $("#perNum").text("Changed");
       $(".picture-hidd").removeClass('hidden').fadeIn(500);
    }
    else
    {
       $("#perNum").text("+2");
       $(".picture-hidd").addClass('hidden').fadeOut(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could toggle a class for this:

---

```js
$('#fade').click(function(){
  $('.fadeable').toggleClass("fade");
  });
```

```css
.fadeable{
  opacity:1;
  transition:all 0.5s;
  }
.fade{
  opacity:0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fadeable">I am going to fade</div>
<button id="fade">Toggle Fade</button>
```

---